# Getting exception in api calling of Channel Order app of Salesforce

Tags: apex, api

I am using channel order app of salesforce and calling the api class through code to submit the service order record but there is something wrong with the class of managed package and throwing the exception -"An error has occurred and the request couldn’t be completed. Please try again and contact salesforce.com if errors continue."

Has anyone worked on this??
Please help me on this

Comment: Mahi, it may help if you include more details in your question, such as the exception that is happening.

Comment: I am creating the service order object record through apex and after that through batch class I am calling the api of channel Order App but I am getting the exception in class - "An error has occurred and the request couldn’t be completed. Please try again and contact salesforce.com if errors continue." As this class is in managed package so I can not see what is the issue in the class...

Comment: Could you edit that additional information into your question ? That'll be more readable to others.

Comment: Ok I have made some changes.